# coupled and non autonomous differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x=f_1(t)$ and $y=f_2(t)$

solve for $x$ and $y$

$\frac{dx}{dt}(y-t)=x-1\dots$           (1)

$\frac{dy}{dt}(x-t)=2\dots$              (2)

I am not finding any method to solve these equations.

Comment: Based on first line, does $x=y$?

Comment: No , i have edited now .

Comment: There are simple solutions but they are not all solutions.  For isntance: $x=1+t$ and $y=2t$.

Comment: Here is another one: $x=1$, and $y'=2/(1-t)$

Answer (score 0):

We can try to show the difficulty of your system of equations, by attempting to eliminate variables.

$$y'=\frac{2}{x-t}$$
Also, with appropriate assumptions regarding the solutions,
$$x'=\frac{x-1}{y-t}$$

Differentiate the last equation:
$$x'' =\frac{x'}{y-t}-\frac{x-1}{\left(y-t\right)^2}\left(y'-1\right)$$
Multiply by $x-1$, we get
$$\left(x-1\right)x''=\frac{x'\left(x-1\right)}{y-t}-\frac{\left(x-1\right)^2}{\left(y-t\right)^2}\left(y'-1\right)=\left(x'\right)^2\left(2-y'\right)$$

Finally substituting $y'$, we see that
$$\left(x-1\right)x''=2\left(x'\right)^2\left(1-\frac{1}{x-t}\right)$$

I do not know of any general solution for this nonlinear differential equation.